# Как получить offsetWidth/Height картинки-элемента с помощью javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

Чтобы разместить мяч посередине элемента field, мне нужно его размер поделить 2, но я не могу поделить его размер на два, т.к. почему-то не получается получить его ширину и высоту никаким способом. 
как картинки элемента в примере ниже правильно получить offsetWidth/Height?

```
  let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
  let field = document.getElementById('field')
  console.log(ball.offsetWidth); -> ВЫВОДИТ 0 почему-то
  ball.style.left = document.body.children[0].clientWidth / 2  + "px"
```

пример полностью

```js
let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
let field = document.getElementById('field')
console.log(ball.offsetWidth);
ball.style.left = document.body.children[0].clientWidth / 2  + "px"
```

```css
#field {
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: relative;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9UdA9ZJJYBiss5vjTBB2?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо это после отрисовки всего делать.

`onload` - Событие на `window` срабатывает, когда загружается вся страница, включая ресурсы на ней – стили, картинки, ифреймы и т.п.

А также, для центровки мяча, с учетом того, что координата *0,0* находится в верхнем правом углу, то помимо половины ширины поля надо еще мяч сместить на половину его ширины влево.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let ball = document.getElementById('ball');
  let field = document.getElementById('field')
  
  console.log('ball width: ' + ball.clientWidth + ', field width: ' + field.clientWidth);
  
  ball.style.left = (field.clientWidth / 2) - (ball.clientWidth / 2)  + "px"
}
```

```css
#field {
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px groove black;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: relative;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball"> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вообще-то я это и хотел сделать, по этому собственно мне и надо узнать было метрику мяча, иначе зачем бы я создавал тему?)
Ещё раз пишу:
Чтобы разместить мяч посередине элемента field, мне нужно его размер поделить 2.

За window.onload спасибо, это всё что я хотел узнать.

Comment: @Anton ну мало ли ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯